# to obtain a parameter for optimization problem

Tags: calculus, optimization, self-learning, linear-programming, finance

Question

$0<a<1 $

$YG\ge 0$

$YE$ is positive

$T=YG-aYE$

$YD=YG+(1-a)YE$

Wage w is positive.

$YE=wH$

Utility function
$$U(Y_D,H)=YD/(1+H)^2$$

Imagine that we need to choose $(YG, a)$ in such a way that utility function is maximized subject to the constraint that T=0. How can we derive the optimal $(YG, a)$.

My solution

$$L=(YD/(1+H)^2)-\lambda (YG-aYE)$$

$$L=((YG+(1-a)YE)/(1+H)^2)-\lambda (YG-aYE)$$

$$L=((YG+(1-a)wH)/(1+H)^2)-\lambda (YG-awH)$$

Derivative with respect to H

$$\frac{w(1+H)^2-2wH(1+H)}{(1+H)^4}=0$$

$$w(1+H)^2-2wH(1+H)=0$$

$$H^*=1/2$$

Then $$YG=aw/2$$

So, $$a^*=2YG^*/w$$

My solution is correct or not? I am not sure at all.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This solution correct or not? I am not sure at all. @Jonas